# Terraform - AWS Network Interface get public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to get the Public Ip in a Network Interface via Terraform.
the output of the NI show me the following json:

```
+ app_lb_ips = [
      + {
          + association       = [
              + {
                  + allocation_id     = ""
                  + association_id    = ""
                  + carrier_ip        = ""
                  + customer_owned_ip = ""
                  + ip_owner_id       = "amazon-elb"
                  + public_dns_name   = "ec2-3cxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com"
                  + public_ip         = "3.xx.xx.50"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I tryied data.aws_network_interface.my_ni.*.association..public_ip but I get a error.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on modules/folder/outputs.tf line 33, in output "app_lb_ips":
│   33:   value = data.aws_network_interface.my_lb.*.association[0].public_dns_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.aws_network_interface.my_lb is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713493/terraform-how-to-get-ip-address-of-aws-lb

Comment: What is your TF code that generates the error?

Comment: The other post talk about the private ip, in the public ip is in the association block...